# Am I correct Insert values into SQL DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public void save(string val)
{
    var insertval = "insert into test_table values(" +val+")";

    try
    {
        DBcon.ConnectionOpen();
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(insertval, DBcon.SqlConn);
        sqlReader.Close();

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd1.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        DBcon.ConnectionClose();
    }
}
```

Comment: please format correctly your code first. First, why do you use `var insertval = "insert into test_table values(" +val+")";` ? use instead `string insertval = "insert into test_table values(" +val+")";` Second.. explain more... there is an error on VS?

Comment: I update the question. Please see it.

Comment: Yes. It is a fine data store. Just do it safely.

Comment: Mark my answer as correct if helped you.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in the sql statement. We don't know what is the value of val, but it should be in `'`, like I wrote it.

```
var insertval = "insert into test_table values('" +val+"')";
```

Also use SqlCommand.Parameters to prevent sql injection in this case you don't need `'`

```
 var insertval = "insert into test_table values(@Value)";
```

And after declaration of SqlCommand add this.

```
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", val);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do that. Look at this line `var insertval = "insert into test_table values(" +val+")";` and tell me what would happen when someone puts `);DROP TABLES` as their first name?